# Convert List<Object[]> to List<MyClass>

Tags: java

```
 List<Object[]> listChild = query.list();
 List<ChildrenDTO> listOfDTO = new ArrayList<>();

 //Loop through arraylits of object
 for(Object[] org: listOrg){
      //How to cast List of object to ist<ChildrenDTO>?
     listOfDTO.add(org);
 }
```

> I am looping through a list of objects and need to return listOfDTO.
>   How to I cast the list to List?

Comment: You don't _cast_ but _convert_, i.e. you take the values in `org` and build an instance of `ChildrenDTO`. How that's done depends on the rest of your code and I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: You will not be able to do this, as there is no way that an array object can be of a non-array type.

Answer (score 3):

If you use java 8, you should give a try to the stream api.

Considering, that the constructor of the DTO has a `String` param.

```java
List<Object[]> listChild = query.list();
List<ChildrenDTO> children = listChild.stream().map(x -> new ChildrenDTO(x[0].toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I tried to used dthos code but instead the list<ChildrenDTO> returned null while the query.list returned values.

Answer (score 1):

So firstly, you're iterating through a List that contains an array of objects.

So, to get each individual object, you need to have a nested loop, something like:

```
        for (Object[] org : listOrg) {
        for (int i = 0; i < org.length; i++) {
            if (org[i] instanceof ChildrenDTO) {
                listOfDTO.add((ChildrenDTO) org[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not 100% sure if you can cast an object to a ChildrenDTO object, but if not, you can just grab the object values and create a new ChildrenDTO instance, maybe a constructor to take the object values?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to write a method that converts **one** Object[] to **one** ChildrenDTO, for instance a constructor:

```
public ChildrenDTO(Object [] objects) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Then you can create a List of those DTO with:

```
    List<ChildrenDTO> listOfDTO = listChild.stream()
            .map(ChildrenDTO::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Java 8 stream API* :

```
List<Object[]> listChild = ...
List<ChildrenDTO> childrenDtos = listChild.stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .filter(object -> Objects.equals(object.getClass(),ChildrenDTO.class))
        //.filter(object -> object instanceof ChildrenDTO) 
        //instead of Objects.equals(class, class), if required
        .map(object -> (ChildrenDTO)object)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```